# Can not register in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have the following code, where the user can enter his display name, email, password in order to set up an account in Firebase.

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private TextInputEditText mDisplayName;
private TextInputEditText mEmail;
private TextInputEditText mPassword;
private Button mCreateBtn;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mDisplayName = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_display_name);
    mEmail = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
    mPassword = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
    mCreateBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reg_create_btn);

    mCreateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String displayName = mDisplayName.getText().toString();
            String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = mPassword.getText().toString();

            registerUser(email,password);

        }


    });
}

private void registerUser(String email, String password) {

   mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
           .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
               @Override
               public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                     if(task.isSuccessful()){
                         sendToMain();
                     }else{
                         Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"You got some error.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }
               }
           });

}

private void sendToMain() {
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(mainIntent);
    finish();
}
```

}

However when I click the button the Toast pops up with a message *You got an error*

It should have worked as I got the idea from [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/EmailPasswordActivity.java)

Why is this happening? My app is connected to Firebase. Also I have enabled Email/Password sign-in method from the console like so.

[image]

So why can't I register?

Thanks,
Theo.

Comment: Can you log - task.getException() instead of Your own alert, it would be much easier that way

Comment: first create user !

Comment: haha. I didn't actually!!! I used        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password){...} instead and things are working:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To register in Firebase, FirebaseAuth has method named `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`. You can use this method to register new User and after of it you can use `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method to authenticate the user.

Answer (score 1):

For firebase registration you have to use createUserWithEmailAndPassword method.